# how does this function inside a class method work in Python?

Tags: python, class, object, methods

It might be a silly question, but I'm new to Python. I would like to understand how the following segment of code is possible.

```
class test:

    def main_method(self):

        variable = 10; 

        def sub_method(input):

            return input * variable

        self.result = sub_method

obj = test()

obj.main_method()

print(obj.result(4))
```

Output:

> 40

My question:

When I execute `obj.result(4)`, how does `self.result`, being an instance variable that stores `sub_method`, has access to the scope of `main_method` and the value of `variable` without executing `main_method` again?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Because `sub_method` keeps the state of the free variables along with it. Python supports [closures](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_(computer_programming))

Comment: I've never heard about it. I'm going to check it out. Thank you

Comment: Also, terminology nitpick: `main_method` just a method, not a class method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is possible because Python functions support [closures](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_(computer_programming)):

> Operationally, a closure is a record storing a function[a] together
>   with an environment:[1] a mapping associating each free variable of
>   the function (variables that are used locally, but defined in an
>   enclosing scope) with the value or reference to which the name was
>   bound when the closure was created.

Indeed, in Python, it is easy to introspect on this. Running your code...

```
In [2]: class test:
   ...:
   ...:     def main_method(self):
   ...:
   ...:         variable = 10;
   ...:
   ...:         def sub_method(input):
   ...:
   ...:             return input * variable
   ...:
   ...:         self.result = sub_method
   ...:
   ...: obj = test()
   ...:
   ...: obj.main_method()
   ...:

In [3]: obj.result
Out[3]: <function __main__.test.main_method.<locals>.sub_method>
```

Basically, each function carries around references to it's free variables:

```
In [6]: obj.result.__closure__
Out[6]: (<cell at 0x10448ff78: int object at 0x100214990>,)

In [7]: obj.result.__closure__[0].cell_contents
Out[7]: 10
```

And even the *names* of it's free variables are introspectable:

```
In [8]: obj.result.__code__.co_freevars
Out[8]: ('variable',)
```

In Python, a function is just another kind of object.